# How to exclude nodes from result?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with one field that shows rendered nodes, and a contextual filter (multiple values allowed) that provides the nids that should be used in the view.

Each node (with nid from the context filter) contains a node reference field with multiple values (nids of related products).

My problem is that a number of these related products, are in fact unpublished nodes. So how can I exclude these unpublished nodes from showing up in the views result? Just adding the filter `Published = Yes` does not work since the field in the view always is published. It is some of the rendered nodes, produced by that field, that in their turn are unpublished.

UPDATE: in a custom module I have now added this snippet:

```
function mymodule_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name === 'my_view' && $view->current_display === 'related_products') {
    foreach ($view->result as $result) {

      foreach($result->field_field_add_products as $key => $product){
        if($product['rendered']['#node']->status == 0){
          unset($result->field_field_add_products[$key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...and this does actually exclude the unwanted products. BUT they don't just leave gracefully. They leave a gap in the (repsonsive) grid that I use to show these products. How do I exclude them AND the space they occupy in my views grid?

UPDATE: this is my PHP snippet in the contextual filter:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
$value = null;
if(empty($node->field_lagg_till_givargrupp['und'][0]['nid'])){
    $node->field_lagg_till_givargrupp['und'][0]['nid'] = NULL;
    return FALSE;
} else {
    $groups = $node->field_lagg_till_givargrupp['und'];
    foreach($groups as $group){
        $group_nid = $group['nid']; // hämta node-id
                $value .= $group_nid.",";
    }
    return rtrim($value, ",");
}
```

It works well and supplies the nids wanted (the node ids for the nodes with multiple products grouped in node reference fields).

And this is a partial screenshot of the view:
[image]

I use the field `Innehåll: Titel` (Content: Title) to group the result by the title of each product group. The field `Innehåll: Koppla givare` (Content: related products) produces all the nodes present in the node reference fields. If there are 20 products entered in that multiple value field, I will have 20 rendered nodes as a result, of which some are not publised. See the resulting view below. The gaps are unpublished nodes that I succeeded in excluding with my snippet above.

[image]

So how do I rebuild the view result so that there are no gaps?

Comment: Hello! can you also post a screenshot of your views setup?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I have updated my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was in fact very simple... though it took me a great deal of time to find the solution. I removed the snippet in the custom module above and instead I added the code below in template.php. Hope it helps somebody. I found the solution here: http://agaric.com/blogs/altering-views-results

```
function mytheme_views_pre_render(&$view) {      
if ($view->name === 'myview' && $view->current_display === 'mydisplay') {
        foreach($view->result as $index=>$val){
          $product_node = node_load($val->field_data_field_related_product_nid);
          if($product_node->status === '0'){
             unset($view->result[$index]);
          }
        }
    }
}
```